# Refreshing a JTable in a client/server application

Tags: java, spring, swing, jtable, rmi

I developed a Java client/server application, communicating via Spring RMI, the Client is symply a swing Jframe how containing at the top a command buttons(add, update, delete), in the middle a JTable, and at the bottom, a form.

the server side contains simply a Dao layer by using iBatis witch communicates with an Apache Derby database.

So the application works greatly, but two problems are found :

1) when the user A adds/updates/deletes a row from a JTable, the others can't see the changes until clicking a button to refresh the data in the JTable, I wanna that this changes must be done automatically.

2) when the user A wants to update a row in the JTable, and the user B wants to changes the same row, when done, always teh programme keeps the last data saved.

can some one give a working code ? or a link to a website, tutorial ....

Answer (score 1):

1) when the user A adds/updates/deletes a row from a JTable, the others can't see the changes until clicking a button to refresh the data in the JTable, I wanna that this changes must be done automatically.

Add a TableModelListener to the TableModel. You will recieve an event whenever data is changed so you can update the server right away.